# Referencing an appended list with user generated class objects from definition within a class?

Tags: python, list, class, physics-engine, projectile

I want to create a class `Ball`, and make a list of objects generated by user for that class. I will then reference this list in `run()` to draw user generated objects in `pygame`. My problems are as follows:

When I try to reference `Ball(a, v, r...)` it says `Ball` is referenced before my definition. Any help is appreciated!

HERE IS FULL ERROR:

```
File "/Users/.../Desktop/.../python/promot.py", line 66, in run
    balls.append(Ball(a, v, r, c, x_pos, y_pos)) #here i get error
                 ^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'Ball' where it is not associated with a value
```

```
import pygame
import math
 
pygame.init()
 
#screen
framespd = 30 #what is frame speed for gravity = 9.81
gravity = 1
t = 0.01
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width, height = 1000, 1000
pygame.display.set_caption("Orbit Take 1")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
 
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, radius, color, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.angle = angle
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
 
    def draw(self):
        self.circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x_pos, self.y_pos), self.radius)
 
    def true_velocity_x(self):
        true_velocity_x = self.velocity * math.cos(self.angle)
 
    def true_velocity_y(self):
        true_velocity_y = self.velocity * math.sin(self.angle)
        new_velocity_y = true_velocity_y + (gravity * t)
 
    #def update position(self):
        #x pos = x velocity
        #y pos += y velocity
 
balls = [] 
 
def run():
    value = True
    while value:
        clock.tick(framespd)
 
        # Balls in sim
 
        number_balls = int(input("How many balls: "))
 
        while len(balls) < number_balls:
            # Variables for Ball
            a = input("Angle: ")
            v = input("Velocity: ")
            r = input("Radius: ")
            c = input("Color: ")
            x_pos = '0'
            y_pos = '500'
            balls.append(Ball(a, v, r, c, x_pos, y_pos)) #here i get error "local variable "Ball" defined in enclosing scope on line 24 referenced before assignment"
 
        screen.fill('black')    
 
        #draw ball
        for Ball in balls:
            Ball.draw(pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)))
        #update position
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                value = False
            pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()       
 
run()
```

My first attempt is referenced in bold as "something else I tried", but I am having trouble using classes outside of their initialization with out errors. My next attempt was "current attempt" which does not show anything when I run.

Comment: Please provide a *single* version of the code, with the *exact*, complete error traceback you get with this version.

Comment: perhaps you wanted `balls` to be a class variable or perhaps you want to make `ball` clearly a singular thing.

Comment: Thanks for the single version of the code, but you need to include the *complete* error traceback, not some vague description of the error.

Comment: please post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: Note that `for Ball in balls:` is a big problem, as it will overwrite `Ball`, which should be your class, which the items contained in `balls`.

Comment: Can you please explain the overwrite - I am not sure how to redefine it as I want a list of objects from Class Ball to generate various balls for projectile motion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first ball this was working correctly but then it encountered the

```
for Ball in balls:
```

statement and then you had a Ball in your namespace so the global variable is overwritten, instead we can call the object ball and run .draw on the ball object.

There was a way around this (if you insist on calling the local variable Ball) by passing the class into the function that I demonstrated as well.

```
def run(cls = Ball):
```

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

# screen
framespd = 30  # what is frame speed for gravity = 9.81
gravity = 1
t = 0.01
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width, height = 1000, 1000
pygame.display.set_caption("Orbit Take 1")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, radius, color, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.angle = angle
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.balls = []

    def draw(self, width, height):
        # We need the inputs of width and height to pass to set_mode
        pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        #self.circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), (self.x_pos, self.y_pos), self.radius)
        # below will always draw a blue circle - tweak color, center and radius to be variables so that you can
        # generate multiple balls with different properties
        self.circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, color=(0, 0, 255), center=(250, 250), radius=75)

    def true_velocity_x(self):
        true_velocity_x = self.velocity * math.cos(self.angle)

    def true_velocity_y(self):
        true_velocity_y = self.velocity * math.sin(self.angle)
        new_velocity_y = true_velocity_y + (gravity * t)

    # def update position(self):
    # x pos = x velocity
    # y pos += y velocity


balls = []


def run():
    value = True
    while value:
        clock.tick(framespd)

        # Balls in sim

        number_balls = int(input("How many balls: "))

        while len(balls) < number_balls:
            # Variables for Ball
            a = input("Angle: ")
            v = input("Velocity: ")
            r = input("Radius: ")
            c = input("Color: ")
            x_pos = '0'
            y_pos = '500'
            balls.append(Ball(a, v, r, c, x_pos,
                              y_pos))  # here i get error "local variable "Ball" defined in enclosing scope on line 24 referenced before assignment"

        screen.fill('black')

        # draw ball
        # call our ball 'ball' so it doesn't overwrite out global class
        for ball in balls:
            ball.draw(width, height)
        # update position

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                value = False
            pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()


run()
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I think it should work however I'm now getting a new error: Ball.draw() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given - does this have to do with width, height and should I consolidate them into one variable?

Comment: This has to do with the method in the class Ball not having any arguments defined.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this change

Comment: How does the method not have args defined? Do I change width and height to x_pos, y_pos?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the change so that draw will work with both width, height passed to it.

Comment: This is now what I get (Thank you for the help so far): self.circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x_pos, self.y_pos), self.radius)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: center argument must be a pair of numbers

Comment: https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/ is a great article helping you understand how to use pygame

Comment: I modified the code to always print a blue circle you can use this line to figure out how to get it to print like you want.

Answer (score 1):

`Ball` is the (global) name of your class.

In your `run` function, you wrote

```
for Ball in balls:
    Ball.draw(pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)))
```

so the name `Balls` will be successively given to each of the balls in `balls` (and will no longer refer to the class, btw).

Python's rule is simple: if you assign to a variable somewhere in the body of a function, then that variable is considered to be local to the function, unless declared otherwise. That's what happens here to `Ball`.

So, as you try to use it before that line, it's a local variable that hasn't received any value, hence the error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'Ball' where it is not associated with a value
```

The solution is simple anyway: don't use this name which should only refer to your class. Just rewrite the loop using a new name for your variable:

```
for ball in balls:
    ball.draw(pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)))
```

Note also that this name is compliant with the [PEP8 recommendation for variable names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), which states that variable names should be all lowercase. Capitalized names are for classes.